# Aramaic-gemara lashon- reverse search

Tags: words, product-recommendation, talmud-gemara, internet, aramaic

Are there any online tools that allow for searching of an english word to produce the gemara/aramaic translation?

I dont really mean translate, I mean to search the jastrow dictionary to find the translation.

Comment: Shloime, [welcome to Mi Yodeya](//judaism.meta.stackexchange.com/a/3887), and thanks very much for bringing your question here! I hope you get helpful answers, and that you also stick around and check out some of our other material. See you around!

Comment: Is this more a question about Aramaic which happens to be in the Gemara and less about Gemara which happens to be in Aramaic?

Answer (score 3):

You can search through the English definitions of the CAL Aramaic dictionary with the [CAL Gloss Search](http://cal.huc.edu/searching/englishnew.html). It includes a number of Aramaic dialects beside the Aramaic used in the Gemara, but if you are only interested in that dialect of Aramaic, then you can check the definitions for the abbreviation "JBA" (= Jewish Babylonian Aramaic) or "Com." (= Common Aramaic).

Comment: note to OP that CAL gives gives links to various aramaic lexicons, such as Jastrow and Sokoloff.  +1, while we're at it.

Comment: Where on site is it? (I don’t see it)

Comment: @Shmuel It's on the page I linked

Comment: What is the link named?

Comment: @Shmuel I linked it on the words "CAL Gloss Search" and the link says "CAL GLOSS Search" at the top of the page

Answer (score 2):

If a search of text will suffice, then you can do a search in online English texts of the Talmud, such as SEFRIA, or The Soncino Talmud Translation (HALAKHAH.com), and search for your English word and then see the corresponding Aramaic word in the original Gemara text. Good luck.